# Restore form(hints) to initial state after submit

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form in html. I am using [Label Over plugin](http://remysharp.com/2007/03/19/a-few-more-jquery-plugins-crop-labelover-and-pluck/#labelOver) to show the labels of the input elements as hints. I am using AJAX to submit information without refreshing the page to a PHP page and returning success/error messages. All this stuff works fine so far.

**The issue is that once I submit the form and receive the success message, my input elements hints disappear.** Without the hints, the user cannot submit another feedback, if they wanted to do so because the input boxes are blank. The only option is to refresh the entire page. I am trying to avoid this. **I just want to show the labels as they were, when the user initially first visited the page.**

In the success function, you will see my comment as //How to Restore labels here??????? That is where I am trying to assign the hints back as they were previously when the page loaded, but the hints dont appear. I am trying to show these hints when success executes so that user can fill out info again & submit again, without ever having to reload the page.

Here is the form:

```
 <form id="frm_contact" name="frm_contact" method="post" action="ajax_contact.php">



            <div class="label">
            <label class="pre" for="name">Enter Name</label>
              <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="42" title="Enter Name" />
            </div>              




            <div class="label">
            <label class="pre" for="email">Enter Email</label>
              <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="42" title="Enter Email" />
            </div>              




         <select name="regarding" id="regarding" style="width: 295px;">
            <option value="">Select a value</option>
            <option value="Comment">Comment</option>
            <option value="Compliment">Compliment</option>
            <option value="Suggestion">Suggestion</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
          </select> 




            <div class="label">
            <label class="pre" for="comments">Comments</label>
             <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="34" rows="5" ></textarea>
            </div>




        <div id="wrap">
                <img src="get_captcha.php" alt="" id="captcha" name="captcha" />

                <img src="images/refresh.gif" alt="Refresh Code" name="refresh" width="48" height="44" id="refresh" title="Refresh Code" />
            </div>                




            <div class="label">
            <label class="pre" for="security_code">Enter Security Code as shown above</label>
            <input name="security_code" type="text" id="security_code" size="42" title="Enter Security Code as shown above" />
            </div>



          <input name="sbt_contact" type="image" id="sbt_contact" src="images/btn_send.jpg" alt="Send" />
</form>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[    
$('label.pre').labelOver('over');

// $(document).ready() is executed after the page DOM id loaded
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Hide loading & success divs by default
    $('#loading').hide();
    $('#result_succcess').hide();

    // Binding an listener to the submit event on the form:
    $('#frm_contact').submit(function(e){

        if($('#sbt_contact').hasClass('active')) return false;              

        // Adding the active class to the button. Will show the preloader gif:
        $('#sbt_contact').addClass('active');

        // Removing the current error tooltips
        $('.errorTip').remove();

        //Show loading icon
        $('#loading').show();

        //Prepare data to be sent
        var dataString = $('#frm_contact').serialize()+'&fromAjax=1';

        $.ajax({

          type: "POST",
          url: "ajax_contact.php",
          data: dataString,
          dataType: 'json',

          success: (function(response) 
            {
                //If no error was found, then clear the entered input
                if(response.error == 0)             
                {
                    /*Completely reset the form if the form is successfully submitted*/
                    $(':input','#frm_contact')
                    .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden, :image')
                    .val('')
                    .removeAttr('checked')
                    .removeAttr('selected');

                    //How to Restore labels here???????
                    //Using the following here, does not restore the labels
                    $('label.pre').labelOver('over');


                    //Remove all the success class for the form elements
                    $('#frm_contact :input').removeClass('success');

                    /*Reset Captcha.*/
                    $("img#refresh").trigger('click');

                    //Show the success box and fade it out after a delay of 10 seconds                  
                    $('#result_succcess').html('Your feedback has been successfully received. We will get back in touch with you shortly.').fadeIn('slow').delay(10000).fadeOut(400);           

                }
                else
                {                   

                    //Remove all the success class that has been previously assgined & do it freshly again
                    $('#frm_contact :input').removeClass('success');

                    // Looping through all the input text boxes,
                    // and checking whether they produced an error
                    $('#frm_contact input[type!=submit], #frm_contact input[type!=image],  #frm_contact select, #frm_contact textarea, #frm_contact input[type=textarea]').each(function(){

                    var elem = $(this);
                    //var id = elem.attr('id');
                    var ele_name = $(this).attr('name');                                        
                    var ele_type = $(this).attr('type');                                

                    //For the errors received, show errors
                    if(response.message[ele_name])
                    {   
                        alert( 'errors' );
                    }
                    else 
                    {

                        if( ele_name != 'sbt_contact' && ele_name != 'refresh' && ele_name != 'captcha' )
                        {
                            alert(ele_name);                            
                        }                   
                    }
                });


                }
            })          

        });                 

        //hide loading icon
        $('#loading').hide();
        e.preventDefault();

    });

});
// ]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into ajaxForm, specifically resetForm, and clearForm

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object

Comment: Thanks for the resource. I actually did come across that when I initially started coding the form. I did not find it to be useful for my purpose because the main functionality of my form is that validation is done using the PHP file whereas Malsup uses validation in JS. Also hints dont work properly. Simply clicking on the input does not clear it. Users have to manually clear it. The current form that I have, solves all my purposes. The only issue I have is with restoring the hints. So if you can throw some light on this, that would be very helpful.